# I have forgotten what the puzzle was

Tags: puzzle-creation, puzzle-identification

I have a notebook in which I draft little puzzles during <strike>meetings</strike> my free time. I came up with one that was to post the acronym version of famous quotes along with the author's initials and the challenge would be to figure out the quote. For the solution to this:

```
ATINFTTOEITGMDN - EB
```

is the full quote and author:

> All that is necessary for the triumph of evil is that good men do nothing. - Edmund Burke
> (This may, in fact, be a [poor example](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Edmund_Burke#Disputed))

Here's another one I wrote down and still remember:

```
NITTFAGMTCTTAOTP - CEW
```

> Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party - Charles E. Weller

Here's the rub, though: I can't remember the solution to the last one I wrote down! This is not a contrived situation. I actually cannot recall what I was thinking because I only wrote down the puzzle; not the solution. I almost want to tag this as [real](/questions/tagged/real) but feel like it doesn't fit with the essence of that tag.

**Can you help me figure out what I was thinking when I wrote down this 
acronym quote?**

```
ILBBAICNLYOBCDTWAGWIWAIBWAARTIYFYGS - SM
```

<sub>FYI:I welcome any better tags</sub>

Comment: Well, here is a convenient list of people with those initials: http://peoplebyinitials.com/?q=SM (Samuel Morse doesn't seem to work)

Comment: The convenient list is inconveniently long, though. (And I doubt that a list that starts with Shkodran Mustafi, a Germany football international, leads to good quotations ...)

Comment: True, but I just thought you might remember the correct person from skimming it.

Comment: No way! I do the exact same thing, except with song lyrics instead of quotes. (I even forgot a couple once and thought to ask on here, but fortunately I'd left hints for myself in the form of doodles.)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I am ashamed this came to me so quickly.

> I like big butts and I can not lie / You other brothers can't deny / That when a girl walks in with an itty bitty waist / And a round thing in your face / You get sprung - Sir Mix-A-Lot

Comment: ...thats... Well then...

Comment: Oh, gosh. I remembered the first two and, thus, was trying to find some lofty famous quote it matched. I would not have thought in this vein for quite some time. This makes me wonder which meeting I was in when my mind wandered so...

Comment: No shame only reputation